# How do apps like Mapbox, AllTrails and Maps.me use and display ALL of OSM data? When all the resources say that's a huge amount of data

Tags: maps, mapbox, openstreetmap

I started exploring Overpass Turbo and Mapbox with hopes of building my travel app. I can query some data in OT and get towns or islands, no problem, I understand the whole process of querying and exporting as Geojson.

But for learning purposes, I always do queries within a small area so I don't get too much data back.

Also, various resources mention that OSM data for the whole planet is huge, like here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data it says: *The entire planet is a huge amount of data. Start with a regional extract to make sure your setup works properly. Common tools like Osmosis or various import tools for database imports and converters take hours or days to import data, depending largely on disk speed.*

But when I go to apps like AllTrails, Maps.me or Mapbox, they seem to be showing a huge amount of data, definitely the main POIs.

[here's an example screenshot from All Trails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxm2O.jpg)

Can someone briefly explain how is this done then? Do they actually download all of data? Or little by little depending on the current bounding box. Any info I can research further, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks

P.S. I am hoping to build my app with Node.js, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Several reasons:

- They don't always display everything. You will always only see a limited region, never the whole world in full detail. If you zoom in, you will see a smaller region but with more details. If you zoom out, you will see a larger region but with reduced details (less or no POIs, smaller roads and waterways disappear etc.).
- They don't contain all the available data. OSM data is very diverse. OSM contains roads, buildings, landuse, addresses, POI information and much more. For each of the mentioned elements, there is additional information available. Roads for instance have maxspeed information, lane count, surface information, whether they are lit and if they have sidewalks or cycleways etc. Buildings may have information about the number of building levels, the building color, roof shape and color and so on. Not all of these information are required for the apps you listed and thus can be removed from the data.
- They perform simplifications. It isn't always necessary to show roads, buildings, waterways and landuse in full detail. Instead, special algorithms reduce the polygon count so that the data becomes smaller while keeping sufficient details. This is often coupled with the zoom level, i.e. roads and lakes will become less detailed if zoomed out.
- They never ship the whole world offline. Depending on the app, the map is either online or offline available, or both. If online, the server has to store the huge amount of data, not the client device. If offline, the map is split into smaller regions that can be handled by the client. This usually means that a certain map only covers a state, a certain region or sometimes a city but rarely a whole country except for smaller countries. If you want to store whole countries offline you will need a significant amount of data storage.
- They never access OSM directly. All apps and websites that display OSM maps don't obtain this information live from OSM. Instead, they either already have a local database containing the required data. This database is periodically updated from the main OSM database via planet dumps. Or they use a third-party map provider (such as MapBox from your screenshot) to display a base map with layers on top. In this case they don't have to store much information on their server, just the things they want to show on top of OSM.

None of the above is specifically for OSM. You will find similar mechanisms in other map apps and for other map sources.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much for your long answer and beautifully organized answers!
I will research further on the concepts you provided, hopefully that will take me somewhere.

Thanks again for taking the time, I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Feel free to accept my answer :)